# 0Auth handshake failed in R

Tags: r, twitter

I am attempting to set up a tweet sentiment analysis tool in R, however I keep getting errors in relation to 0Auth not completing it's handshake.

it's using a tutorial that I found online, however I'm new to R and coding in general so I'm stumped.

Any light that can be shed on this would be much appreciated:

```
install.packages("twitteR")
install.packages("plyr")
install.packages("stringr")
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("streamR")

library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(plyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

## Windows users need to get this file
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")

requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey = "conkey code"
consumerSecret = "consec code"

Cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                         consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                         requestURL=requestURL,
                         accessURL=accessURL, 
                         authURL=authURL)
Cred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl") )
1340490

load("twitter authentication.Rdata")
registerTwitterOAuth(Cred)
```

Comment: This has been asked many times.  See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+OAuth+handshake+failed+in+R

Comment: Possible duplicat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347233/ssl-certificate-failed-for-twitter-in-r or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916283/twitter-roauth-and-windows-register-ok-but-certificate-verify-failed or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122879/roauth-on-windows-using-r

Comment: I've tried many of those solutions, most of which are before the implementation of an updated version of the twitter API, So afaik none of them work the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the creators github page:(https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/blob/master/README.md) It's an easier way to do it. You will also need to install Rtools if you are going to do it this way. Here is a youtube link that shows you how to install Rtools(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enPPMHr5SrM) it is in Chinese but you can still follow what this guy is doing. I hope this helps.