# Connect to Secured Elastic Search with self-signed certificate from elastic R package

Tags: r, curl, elasticsearch, ropensci

I am running an `Elastic Search` instance with SSL by creating a self-signed certificate. I ran into a problem when connecting from R through `elastic` package. 
This is how I progressed:

After enabling SSL, when I tried to connect to the Elastic Search instance, I got the below error:

```
$ curl -u $USER:$PASS 'https://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v'
curl: (60) Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

As evident, this problem is because of the certificate not been trusted. One way is to just add the self-signed certificate to the truststore, but I don't know where it is. Other way is to just skip certificate verification by adding -k. But I wanted to perform it.
Hence I found a work-around to just specify the `root-ca.pem` as below:

```
$ curl -u $USER:$PASS 'https://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v' --cacert /home/user/root-ca.pem
epoch      timestamp cluster     status node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign pending_tasks max_task_wait_time active_shards_percent
1479462058 03:40:58  es-cluster yellow          1         1    365 365    0    0      364             0                  -                 50.1%
```

Then another SO question helped me create a file `~/.curlrc` as below:

```
$ cat ~/.curlrc
capath=/home/user/
```

After that, I didn't had to specify the certificate even.

```
$ curl -u $USER:$PASS 'https://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v'
epoch      timestamp cluster     status node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign pending_tasks max_task_wait_time active_shards_percent
1479462172 03:42:52  es-cluster yellow          1         1    365 365    0    0      364             0                  -                 50.1%
```

All well till now, but now when I am trying to connect to Elastic Search from `R`. I am getting the below error.

```
> library(elastic)
> connect(es_base = "https://localhost", es_port = 9200, es_user = USER,   es_pwd = PASS)
Error:
  Failed to connect to https://127.0.0.1:9200
  Remember to start Elasticsearch before connecting
```

The logs report `unknown_ca` error. `elastic` R package might be using either httr/curl to make the connection but I couldn't figure out how to specify the certificate.
I referred the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122879/roauth-on-windows-using-r) but it works for `RCurl`.

Please suggest.

Versions:

- R : 3.3.1
- R (Elastic package) : 0.7.8
- Elastic Search: 2.4.1
- OS: RHEL 6.7

Comment: You're looking for the `cainfo` curl option, and I think you'll need to set `ssl_verifypeer` and `ssl_verifyhost` as well. After `connect()`, pass in to other functions, e,.g, `Search(config = list(cainfo = "/home/user/root-ca.pem", ssl_verifypeer = 0, `ssl_verifyhost = 0)`

Comment: Thanks @sckott . Your suggestion helped. I will post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @sckott, I had to set the `cainfo` parameter.
Below is what worked in my case:

```
library(elastic)
library(httr)
set_config(config(cainfo = "/home/user/root-ca.pem"))
connect(es_base = "https://localhost", es_port = 9200, es_user = USER,   es_pwd = PASS)
```

Thank you Sckott.